# How do I get totals for two colums with a checkbox to show using jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery

I need to get the total price and total tax of the two rows to add up and show in their total row when checkbox is checked and button is submitted using jquery or javascript. Here is what I have so far.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
  var totalVal = "";
  var qty, price;
  $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each (function (){
    price = $(this).parent().parent().find().val();
    price2 = $(this).parent().parent().find().text();

    totalVal = parseInt(sales1) += parseInt(sales2);
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.totalCost').text(totalVal);
  });
});​
</script>
```

```
<table cellpadding="2">
    <thead>
    <tr >
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Total Sales</th>
        <th>Tax</th>
        <th>State</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"  id="item1"></td>
        <td>9/19/13</td>
        <td class="sales1">$10.00</td>
        <td class="tax1">$1.00</td>
        <td>WA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="item2"></td>
        <td>9/20/13</td>
        <td class="sales2">$5.00</td>
        <td class="tax2">$.0.50</td>
        <td>CA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><tfoot><td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="totalCost"></td>
            <td class="totalTax"></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td></tfoot>
    </tr>   
</table>
​
<p><input type="submit" id="totalcost" value="Submit" ></p>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pTbXf/) should get you started.

It's not elegant, but works.

I'm not sure what you meant about the checkbox. You'll have to explain further.

If you could put the number in a span or the $ in a span, the calculation would be easier.

JS

```
$('#totalcost').click(function(){
var sumcount = 0;
  var smallnumber = 0;
  $('.maintable tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function(index, element) {
      smallnumber = $(this).text();
      smallnumber = smallnumber.substring(1, smallnumber.length-1);
      smallnumber = +smallnumber;
      sumcount = sumcount + smallnumber;
                                                                    });
$('.totalCost').html(sumcount);

  var sumcount2 = 0;
  var smallnumber2 = 0;
  $('.maintable tr td:nth-child(4)').each(function(index, element) {
      smallnumber2 = $(this).text();
      smallnumber2 = smallnumber2.substring(1, smallnumber2.length-1);
      smallnumber2 = +smallnumber2;
      sumcount2 = sumcount2 + smallnumber2;
                                                                    });
$('.totalTax').html(sumcount2);
});
```